# String within substring

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string in a list as:

```
myData=["GndWork0920932jdjs-----#2.35 InherenowanotheeStemWork83kkjkfjks-----#4.55"]
```

I would like to first find 'Gnd' then get the value '2.35' then I want to find Stem and get the value '4.55'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer will probably not be useful but if for some reason there is a real-world application with such arbitrary data formats and the number of cases to consider are finite, then perhaps

```
import re

myData=["GndWork0920932jdjs-----#2.35 InherenowanotheeStemWork83kkjkfjks-----#4.55"]
regex = re.compile(".*(Gnd|Stem).*-----#(.+)")

for s in myData[0].split():
  m = regex.match(s)
  print(m.group(1), m.group(2))
```